# how to optimize high sort cost and scan count

Tags: sql, sql-server

```sql
SELECT 
    CONVERT(INT, 0) AS SeqNo,
    id AS ID,
    [pi no] AS InvoiceNo,
    [pi date] AS InvoiceDate,
    PM.partyname AS VENDORNAME,
    docno AS DOCNO,
    (
        CASE 
            WHEN [docdate] = '0001-01-01' THEN NULL
            WHEN [docdate] = '1900-01-01' THEN NULL
            ELSE [docdate]
            END
        ) AS DOCDATE,
    AD.againstinvoiceno AS AgainstNo,
    (
        CASE 
            WHEN AD.againstinvoicedate = '0001-01-01' THEN NULL
            WHEN AD.againstinvoicedate = '1900-01-01' THEN NULL
            ELSE AD.againstinvoicedate
            END
        ) AS AgainstDate,
    Isnull(
        Stuff((
                SELECT 
                    CHAR(10) 
                    + ('[ ' 
                        + BR.againstinvoiceno 
                        + ' - ' 
                        + CONVERT(VARCHAR(100), BR.againstinvoicedate, 103) 
                        + ' ]')
                FROM (
                        SELECT 
                            pimasterid,
                            againstinvoiceno,
                            againstinvoicedate
                        FROM purchaseinvoicedetails
                        WHERE againstinvoiceid > 0
                        GROUP BY 
                            pimasterid,
                            againstinvoiceno,
                            againstinvoicedate
                        ) BR
                WHERE PIM.id = BR.pimasterid
                FOR XML path('')
        ), 1, 1, ''), 
    '') AS AgainstInfo,
    PIM.[net pivalue] AS NetAmount
FROM purchaseinvoice PIM
LEFT JOIN (
              SELECT 
                PIND.pimasterid,
                againstinvoiceno,
                againstinvoicedate
              FROM purchaseinvoicedetails PIND
              INNER JOIN (
                        SELECT 
                            pimasterid,
                            Min(id) AS MINID
                        FROM purchaseinvoicedetails
                        WHERE againstinvoiceid > 0
                        GROUP BY pimasterid
                ) MINRD ON MINRD.minid = PIND.id
            ) AD ON AD.pimasterid = PIM.id
INNER JOIN (
            SELECT 
                partycode,
                partyname
            FROM partymaster
        ) PM ON PM.partycode = PIM.[vendor id]
WHERE PIM.[status] = 0
    AND PIM.loccode = 1
ORDER BY id DESC
```

I need to optimize the query which has been mentioned above. It takes more than a one min to show the results sometimes.
We have checked table which has no indexes,so we have added indexes based on the Tuning advisor recommedations,
after that it shows high scan count and sort cost.Could you please help to fix this?

Comment: You should provide sample data, desired results, and explain what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: A subquery within a subquery always has a bit of a code smell, if I am honest. Also, why are  *all* your joins to subqueries (including the one in the `SELECT`)?

Comment: Your query logic is a bit hard to understand, eg what is the difference between BR and AD subqueries etc? Maybe you try to simplify your queries, remove unnecessary subqueries (PM for example) and explain your logic a bit. Query plans would help too; tuning advisor hints are not always optimal either,

Comment: Additionally, if there are implicit type conversions between any of the columns when you are JOINing them, the performance is far worse than if the types were identical.